# Apex trigger to update checkbox in related field

Tags: apex, trigger, lookup

new at Apex having an issue with creating a trigger.
I'm trying to update the value of a picklist depending on if a checkbox is checked in Carrier_Product__c. I know you cannot do this method, and it relies on another lookup where it won't return null.
Here's what I have, thank you.

```
trigger ShellPolicyRebalance on Quote_Policy__c(before insert) {
  for (Quote_Policy__c p: Trigger.new) {
    if (p.RecordTypeId == Schema.SObjectType.Quote_Policy__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Shell Policy').getRecordTypeId()) {
      if (p.Carrier_Product__r.Rebalance__c) {
        p.Renewal_Flow__c = 'Rebalance';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably doable in a flow... but to do this in a trigger, there are some generic steps that you can follow.

1. Get get all the carrier product ids. Put them in a list or a set by looping `Trigger.new`
2. Query the `Carrier_Product__c` object to get the checkbox field that you want. eg `[SELECT Id, Rebalance__c FROM Carrier_Product__c WHERE Id IN :carrierProductIdList ];`
3. Put the results of this query into a `Map<Id,Carrier_Product__c>`
4. Loop `Trigger.new` and use the product id to get the correct carrier product out of the map.
5. Examine the value and set/unset the checkbox.
6. This should be a before trigger, so you don't need to update.

Comment: I ended up using a flow, but this was great at teaching how it could have been done with a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot get relationships value   in trigger.new .   p.Carrier_Product__r.Rebalance__c   will not return correct value.

use  after  insert  instead  of  before insert   and  iterate  over records   using  soql.   finally   update  records  using   dml.

something like that  (just a sample code.  did  not tested it.  you might also  want to include recursive check.)

```
trigger ShellPolicyRebalance on Quote_Policy__c(after insert) {
  List<Quote_Policy__c> recordsToUpdate = new List<Quote_Policy__c>();
  for (Quote_Policy__c p: [select id,recordtypeid,Carrier_Product__r.Rebalance__c,Renewal_Flow__c  from Quote_Policy__c   where id in :Trigger.new) {
    if (p.RecordTypeId == Schema.SObjectType.Quote_Policy__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Shell Policy').getRecordTypeId()) {
      if (p.Carrier_Product__r.Rebalance__c) {
        p.Renewal_Flow__c = 'Rebalance';
        recordsToUpdate.add(p);
      }
    }
  }

if(recordsToUpdate.size()>0)
  update recordsToUpdate ;
}
```

on a side  note, your problem statement  is more suited for  flow.  flow will be a better option than trigger.

Comment: If `Carrier_Product__c` is populated, then it's still possible to use a `before insert` trigger here (by using the steps outlined by Caspar). This would remove the need for an extra DML call at the end.

Comment: Also, there is no need to check if a list is empty before performing DML. Salesforce does that sanity check for us, and is even kind enough to not count it against the DML operations governor limit if the list is empty.

Comment: @Derek F.   agreed.  it  can be done in before  insert  as   outlined by casper.  before insert  approach  using map did  not clicked  me while answering.  appreciate  your feedback.